# Swift: Unexpected zoom in ad

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, mopub

I added the MoPub banner ad with the following code:

```
 self.adView.delegate = self
    self.adView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height - MOPUB_BANNER_SIZE.height,
        screenWidth, MOPUB_BANNER_SIZE.height)
    self.view.addSubview(self.adView)
    self.adView.loadAd()
```

For some reason when I run the application the screen doesn't appear fully, but it has a weird zoom. What could be happening?

[image]

**UPDATE:**

I moved the frame of the adView to `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
 self.adView.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(self.adView)
    self.adView.loadAd()
}


  override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

    var screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    var screenWidth = screenSize.width

    self.adView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height - MOPUB_BANNER_SIZE.height,
        MOPUB_BANNER_SIZE.width, MOPUB_BANNER_SIZE.height)

}
```

But the error persists, **I'm using Auto Layout and Size Classes**.

Comment: where is that code written or from where is it called from? From `viewDidLoad`? There is no layout information present in `viewDidLoad`, therefore the frames and sizes are potentially wrong.

Comment: @luk2302 Yes, its positioned in viewDidLoad, why are they wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by myself. When working with Spritekit and scenes, remember to always **configure the scene before presenting it**, specially the scene's **ScaleMode**. After setting the scene's scaleMode to: `scaleMode= .Fill` the zoom stopped happening.

Answer (score 0):

The frame properties that are present in `viewDidLoad` do not reflect the actual frame properties of the view that will be presented on screen. In this method the outlets have been created and all that, but not layed out yet.

Therefore it is the correct place to create an AdView, setting its properties...

**BUT** the layout has to be done somewhere else - the best place is `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. If this method is called you can be sure that the frame properties are set correctly.

Before changing anything in your code you can just log the frame in `viewDidLoad` and log them in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` - they should be different. Then you can go ahead and move your layout logic over there as well.

Comment: I moved the self.AdView.frame to the viewDidLayoutSubviews but the zoom is still appearing.

Comment: @OmarDlhz have you tried logging the frame and see if that property actually makes sense? Btw: i forgot to ask: are you using auto layout?

Comment: Yes, I'm using autolayout. How do I log the frame? I just copied the code as it appears in the mopub website.

Comment: @OmarDlhz okay, if you are using autolayout you cannot set the frame at all - you have to manipulate the layout constraints.

Comment: I even disabled size classes and the problem persists.